# TCPDF table text not showing

Tags: php, html, pdf, tcpdf

I have used TCPDF in generating schedules that requires PDF format. But my text doesn't show up on the generated PDF. I did some HTML validation and the HTML seems to be valid. Any pointers on what might be wrong?

PDF File: https://www.dropbox.com/s/42s6cyi0dzawcto/pdfschedule_March_2015_f1e4e194a7f32e2.pdf?dl=0

HTML snippet:

```
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" class="calendar">
    <tr class="calendar-row">
        <td style="background-color: #DDD; border:1px black solid;" class="calendar-day-head">Sunday</td>
        <td class="calendar-day-head" style="background-color: #DDD; border:1px black solid;">Monday</td>
        <td class="calendar-day-head" style="background-color: #DDD; border:1px black solid;">Tuesday</td>
        <td class="calendar-day-head" style="background-color: #DDD; border:1px black solid;">Wednesday</td>
        <td class="calendar-day-head" style="background-color: #DDD; border:1px black solid;">Thursday</td>
        <td class="calendar-day-head" style="background-color: #DDD; border:1px black solid;">Friday</td>
        <td class="calendar-day-head" style="background-color: #DDD; border:1px black solid;">Saturday</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="calendar-row">
        <td style="vertical-align:top; border: 1px solid black;">March 15, 2015<br/></td>
        <td style="vertical-align:top; border: 1px solid black;">March 16, 2015<br/></td>
        <td style="vertical-align:top; border: 1px solid black;">March 17, 2015<br/></td>
        <td style="vertical-align:top; border: 1px solid black;">March 18, 2015<br/></td>
        <td style="vertical-align:top; border: 1px solid black;">March 19, 2015<br/></td>
        <td style="vertical-align:top; border: 1px solid black;">March 20, 2015<br/></td>
        <td style="vertical-align:top; border: 1px solid black;">March 21, 2015<br/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align:top; border: 1px solid black; background-color: #fae3e3;" colspan="7"><span
                style="background-color: #fae3e3;"><a style=" font-size:9pt; margin-left:5px; text-decoration:none;"
                                                      target="_blank" href="index.php?id=29">Asr123 Ø£Ø­Ù…Ø±
            ØºØ§Ù…Ù‚ </a></span><br/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td style="vertical-align:top; border: 1px solid black; background-color: #fdf1ba;" colspan="1"><span
                style="background-color: #fdf1ba;"><a style=" font-size:9pt; margin-left:5px; text-decoration:none;"
                                                      target="_blank" href="index.php?id=33">Ø¹Ø±Ø¨ÙŠ</a></span><br/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td style="vertical-align:top; border: 1px solid black; background-color: #d1e8ff;" colspan="1"><span
                style="background-color: #d1e8ff;"><a style=" font-size:9pt; margin-left:5px; text-decoration:none;"
                                                      target="_blank" href="index.php?id=34">5555</a></span><br/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td style="vertical-align:top; border: 1px solid black; background-color: #d1e8ff;" colspan="5"><span
                style="background-color: #d1e8ff;"><a style=" font-size:9pt; margin-left:5px; text-decoration:none;"
                                                      target="_blank" href="index.php?id=36">apple juce</a></span><br/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td style="vertical-align:top; border: 1px solid black; background-color: #d1e8ff;" colspan="5"><span
                style="background-color: #d1e8ff;"><a style=" font-size:9pt; margin-left:5px; text-decoration:none;"
                                                      target="_blank" href="index.php?id=39">NEW ROLL
            PC1001</a></span><br/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td style="vertical-align:top; border: 1px solid black; background-color: #fae3e3;" colspan="1"><span
                style="background-color: #fae3e3;"><a style=" font-size:9pt; margin-left:5px; text-decoration:none;"
                                                      target="_blank" href="index.php?id=35">No
            Description</a></span><br/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

PHP Snippet: TCPDF config

```
$pdf = new TCPDF("L", PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);    

$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor( 'AUTHOR');
$pdf->SetTitle('TITLE');
$pdf->SetSubject('SUBJECT');
$pdf->SetKeywords('KEYWORD');    


$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 018', PDF_HEADER_STRING);    

$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));    

$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);    

$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);    

$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);    

$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);    

$lg = Array();
$lg['a_meta_charset'] = 'UTF-8';
$lg['a_meta_dir'] = 'ltr';
$lg['a_meta_language'] = 'fa';
$lg['w_page'] = 'page';    
$pdf->setLanguageArray($lg);
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 10);
$pdf->SetMargins(10, 5, 10);
$pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);
$pdf->setCellHeightRatio(1.25);
$pdf->setFontSubsetting(false);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->WriteHTML($html, true, 0, true, 0);
$pdf->Output( 'pdf/' . $file , 'D');
```

Please take note that the $scheduler object has already been instantiated and is working fine, in which returns the HTML output posted above.

Comment: Sorry, could you please post your php code? How do you expect us to help without?

Comment: Apologies for that, a PHP source is included.
http://codepad.org/gA7ShsLN

Comment: Sorry, please post all relevant code _here on the page_. Do not just link to it. There are reasons for that, you may want to read the "how to ask questions" section here... you should always directly post the code, stripped down to the relevant bits that are enough to reproduce the issue. You have to reduce things anyway, since no one here is going to dig through a whole application...

Comment: In your php code I cannot spot anything where out actually output something to the document, so what do you expect to see on it?

Comment: Updated with HTML and PHP snippet. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: Updated with code for output. The PDF outputs fine as a document except for the missing text.

Comment: I tried your code, it works fine for my AFAICS. Any specific text detail you miss? http://imagebin.ca/v/1wVjNMnPozdG

Comment: I have just checked, it works fine on Reader for Windows 8.1, Mozilla's PDF Reader, but not on Chrome's PDF Reader when using the Deja Vu Sans font. But when I use Helvetica, it works fine. But I should use Deja Vu Sans to correctly display Arabic characters.

Comment: That sounds more like an issue with the fonts, not with tcpdf as such! I suggest you include all fonts you use into the document. Best is to use free web fonts in such case. That prevents legal issues when bundling fonts. For example you may _not_ use MS fonts like that, AFAIK... If the fonts are not available at runtime, then the pdf interpreter will most likely chose an alternative it belives to be fit for the purpose. Then if that chosen font does not include the characters you use in the document, white patches may be the result. So bundling the fonts brings you on the safe side...

Comment: Or it is yet another deficiency of Chrome's PDF Reader...